# Relationship between Maclaurin and Hermite coefficients of a function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, gaussian-integral, hermite-polynomials

Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $\mathcal C^\infty$ around $0$, and square-integrable w.r.t the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Let $a_n:=g^{(n)}(0)/n!$ be the $n$ Maclaurin coefficient of $g$ and let $b_n := \mathbb E_{z \sim N(0,1)}[g(z)H_n(z)]$ be the $n$th Hermite coefficient of $g$, where $H_n$ is the probabilist's $n$th Hermite polynomial.

> **Question.** *Is there any relationship whatsoever between the $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s ?*

Of course, $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n H_n(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and so

- $a_0 = g(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n H_n(0) = b_0-b_2+3b_4 + \ldots$
- $a_1 = g'(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(g') H_n(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+1} H_n(0)$, since $b_n(g') = b_{n+1}(g)$ for all $n$.
- ...
- More generall, $a_k := g^{(k)}(0)/ k! = (1/k!)\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+k} H_n(0)$, for all $k \ge 0$,

I was just wondering if this can  be made any simpler / more compact...

Comment: I don't think your hypotheses imply pointwise convergence of the sequence of $L^2(e^{-x^2/2} dx)$ projections onto polynomial subspaces. I could be wrong, though. (In any case this comparison makes more sense when $g$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$, and in that case there is no problem.)

Comment: Indeed. However, square-integrability + $\mathcal C^1$ are sufficient. Updated.

Comment: Pretty sure you now just have convergence in $L^2(e^{-x^2/2} dx)$ instead, with no guarantee about pointwise convergence. Sorry to nitpick, but it seems related to the question; it really does seem like a real analyticity assumption together with the integrability requirement is the most natural starting point here.

Comment: There is indeed pointwise convergence: https://mathoverflow.net/a/145235/78539

Comment: Regarding the second part of your comment, well, since I'm in the business of comparing Maclaurin coefficients with some other stuff, it is only natural to assume that all the Macluarin coefficients exist, to begin with. Therefore the assumption that $g$ is $C^\infty$. No ?

Comment: Huh, that's a surprisingly convenient result in that link, nice.